# How do I add a label that is asynchronously downloaded from Firestore to an SKNode in ARkit?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, return, arkit

I am trying to take data from a field in Firestore which happens in the get number function which works :) Then I want to use it as the label for an SKnode in ARKit but because data from Firestore is called asynchronously the label cannot be directly returned within the completion block and if the label node is created outside then it does not have the updated value from firestore?

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) ->  SKNode? {

    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
    let ImageName = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name,
    let scannedImage = self.images[ImageName]
        else { return nil}

        getNumber{ number in

             let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: number)
             labelNode.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
             labelNode.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
             //return labelnode; - doesnt work because it is in the completion block


        }
    //return labelNode; - doesnt work because labelnode is not defined - this runs before the completion block


}
```

Comment: You have to come up with a way to separate your model from your view because right now you have them completely joined. Typically, the creation of the view and the creation of the model are separate.